# How to config minified React+ReactDOM with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

After too many unsuccessful trials my question is: **What is the proper way to setup Webpack** so that:

1. Use react.min.js + react-dom.min.js - not the npm installed sources
2. Don't parse/com them again, just bundle with my own components.
3. "React" and "ReactDOM" variables can be used from all .jsx files.

The tutorials and guides I found didn't work - or maybe I did some errors. Usually I got error in browser developer tools about missing variable React.

My aim is just to save parsing/bundling time. Now I parse React from scratch every time I bundle my app. And it takes tens of seconds on a slowish computer. In watch mode it is faster, but I find I'm doing unnecessary work.

Any ideas with recent React versions?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have a `webpack.config.js` that looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
        ]
    }
};
```

You just need to specify `React` and `ReactDOM` as external dependencies ([from the docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        // "node/npm module name": "name of exported library variable"
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

The key point about the `externals` section is that the key is the *name of the module you want to reference*, and the value is the *name of the variable that the library exposes when used in a <script> tag*.

In this example, using the following two script tags:

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.6.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.6.js"></script>
```

results in two top-level variables being created: `React` and `ReactDOM`.

With the above `externals` configuration, anytime in your source code you have a `require('react')`, it will return the value of the global variable `React` instead of bundling react with your output.

However, in order to do this the page that includes your bundle *must* include the referenced libraries (in this case `react` and `react-dom`) *before* including your bundle.

Hope that helps!

---

*edit*

Okay I see what you're trying to do. The webpack configuration option you want is [`module.noParse`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-noparse).

> This disables parsing by webpack. Therefore you cannot use dependencies. This may be useful for prepackaged libraries.

For [example](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#configuration-option-module-noparse):

```
{
    module: {
        noParse: [
            /XModule[\\\/]file\.js$/,
            path.join(__dirname, "web_modules", "XModule2")
        ]
    }
}
```

So you'd have your `react.min.js`, `react-dom.min.js`, and `jquery.min.js` files in some folder (say `./prebuilt`), and then you'd require them like any other local module:

```
var react = require('./prebuilt/react.min');
```

And the entry in `webpack.config.js` would look something like this (untested):

```
{
    module: {
        noParse: [
            /prebuilt[\\\/].*\.js$/
        ]
    }
}
```

The `[\\\/]` mess is for matching paths on both Windows and OSX/Linux.

Comment: Thanks, will try! Is there a way to accomplish all that without using <script> tags in the html file? Basically so that I have these files:

"mysource.jsx"
"react.min.js"
"react-dom.min.js"
"jquery.min.js"

And webpack makes a "bundle.js" from those four files? And I could just var React = require("react") in mysource.jsx.

Comment: Edited my answer to add some more info.

Comment: I'm having a problem. Everytime I use `require(...)` a new copy of the module is imported. This breaks React with refs giving `addComponentAsRefTo` error. If I don't use `require` and just directly use `React`, then it works just fine. But I rather to import modules that I want to use.